# Sum Of mysql table record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `tbl_Question` and a column named `INT_MARK` which has different marks for different questions. Like this:

```
VH_QUESTION     INT_MARK
-----------     --------
Q1              2
Q2              4
```

My question is: How to get a random set of 20 questions whose total sum of marks is 50?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396/245679)

Comment: You'll need an algorithm, this is more a mathematical question, once you know the strategy, it will be to convert it to SQL query!

Comment: A start: a) Pick 20 random questions. b) Do they add up to 50? c) If not, repeat.

Comment: SQL is about set-based solutions, while this problem, even though it's dealing with a data set, should probably be solved iteratively, and that generally isn't SQL's strongest suit.

Answer (score 1):

```
select VH_QUESTION, sum(INT_MARK) from tbl_Question
 group by VH_QUESTION
having sum(INT_MARK) > 50 
order by rand() limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335184/find-combinations-that-meet-a-ranged-criteria) may help you - seems a very similar problem.

If that don't work, I'd try to divide the problem in two: first, you make a combinatory of your questions. Then, you filter them by it's sum of points.

I couldn't find, however, how to produce all combinations of the table. I don't know how difficult that would be.

Answer (score 0):

```
select VH_QUESTION, sum(INT_MARK) from tbl_Question
group by VH_QUESTION
having sum(INT_MARK) >= 50 
order by rand() limit 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer

```
SELECT * ,SUM(INT_MARK) as total_mark FROM tbl_Question  
GROUP BY VH_QUESTION
HAVING total_mark="50"
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

it returns 0 line when no answers are possible but each time it finds one the questionsare random.

**You could check the benchmark to see if you can have a faster query for large tables.**